# Texel data in case of GL_LUMINANCE when glTexImage2D is called

Tags: opengl, texel

Usually a texel is an RGBA value. What data does a texel represent in the following code:

```
const int TEXELS_W = 2, TEXELS_H = 2;
GLubyte texels[] = {
    100, 200,  0,  0,
    200,  250,  0,  0
};
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    0,                  // mipmap reduction level
    GL_LUMINANCE,
    TEXELS_W,
    TEXELS_H,
    0,                  // border (must be 0)
    GL_LUMINANCE,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    texels);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
GLubyte texels[] = {
    100, 200,  0,  0,
    200,  250,  0,  0
};
```

OpenGL will only read 4 of these values. Because `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` defaults to 4, OpenGL expects [each row of pixel data to be aligned to 4 bytes](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_transfer_parameters). So the two 0's in each row are just padding, because the person who wrote this code didn't know how to change the alignment.

So OpenGL will read `100, 200` as the first row, then skip to the next 4 byte boundary and read `200, 250` as the second row.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Why I can't write "GLubyte texels[] = {
    100, 200,  
    200,  250
};" and expect to have 4 texels for luminance then?

Comment: @Narek: The reason is the *second sentence* I wrote. Regardless of how big the input array is, a 2x2 texture will only have 4 texels.

Comment: I think I got the idea. If it read the full row of the pixels, and data is not yet multiple of 4 byte, it will skip several bytes to align to 4 and then read the next row of pixels, right?

Answer (score 1):

> [`GL_LUMINANCE`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml):
>
> Each element is a single luminance value.  **The GL converts it to floating point, then assembles it into an RGBA element by replicating the luminance value three times for red, green, and blue and attaching 1 for alpha**.  Each component is then multiplied by the signed scale factor `GL_c_SCALE`, added to the signed bias `GL_c_BIAS`, and clamped to the range [0,1] (see `glPixelTransfer`).

Comment: I have read this, but as much as I understand I should have only one value for luminance. But in the example above it has 2 values per texel. Why?

Comment: @Narek: No, it doesn't. OpenGL only reads 4 of those values, no matter how many are in the array.